# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080 on Windows

Tags: typescript

Tried to figure out what was causing the following error after doing `node filename.js`. IN each line containing the targeted address on my laptop. *@node-wot* was underlined

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1334:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1382:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1469:7)
    at C:\Users\X\node_modules\@node-wot\binding-http\dist\http-server.js:135:26
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at HttpServer.start (C:\Users\X\node_modules\@node-wot\binding-http\dist\http-server.js:124:16)
    at C:\Users\X\node_modules\@node-wot\core\dist\servient.js:198:82
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Servient.start (C:\Users\X\node_modules\@node-wot\core\dist\servient.js:198:22)
    at C:\Users\X\filename.js:355:22 {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 8080
}
```

I used *netstat -ano|findstr "PID :::8080"* and it displayed nothing which is abnormal.

Comment: Just for fun, try a restart of your system and run this again.. :-)

Comment: @NalinRanjan I tried it but still nothing

Comment: Does it run fine on port 8081 or any other ??

Comment: @NalinRanjan nope. Maybe this could be helpful in order to help me, but I had a copy of the folder I'm actually getting the error from. So basically in folder "A" I am getting an error. In folder "B" which is outside folder "A" the error does not occur. IN the morning, I tried running my code from folder "B" on a localhost. 
Is this helpful?

Comment: can you check `TaskManager → Performance tab` to see which process is listening on port `8080`?

Comment: The format `:::8080` shown by this code is nonstandard; maybe it was not updated for IPv6. **Try `netstat -ano | findstr \[::]:8080` instead.**